# How to deal with 'ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (10000,) (10000,10) ' in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

There is a part of the code:

```
batch = getRandomBatch(batch_size)
users_ind = batch[0, :, 0]
items_ind = batch[0, :, 2]
for i in range(25):
    sum_loss, err = computeLossFunction(batch)
    users_mat[users_ind, :] += err*items_mat[items_ind, :]
```

It throws an ValueError, 'operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (10000,) (10000,10) ' in `users_mat[users_ind, :] += err*items_mat[items_ind, :]` I dont know how to deal with it.
And Why the shape of err is (10000,) instead of (10000,1)?

========================================================================

```
users_mat = np.random.rand(len_users, latent_space_dimension)
items_mat = np.random.rand(len_items, latent_space_dimension)
def getRandomBatch(batch_size):
    batch = np.random.choice(len_data_mat-1, size=(1, batch_size))
    batch = data_mat[batch]
    return batch

def computeLossFunction(data_mat):
    items_ind = data_mat[0, :, 2]
    rates = data_mat[0, :, 1]
    users_ind = data_mat[0, :, 0]
    vector_items = items_mat[items_ind, :]
    vector_users = users_mat[users_ind, :]
    dot_list = np.sum(vector_items*vector_users, axis=1)
    err = rates-dot_list
    piece = np.power(err, 2)+lambda_val*(np.sum(np.power(vector_users, 2), axis=1) + np.sum(np.power(vector_items, 2), axis=1))
    sum_loss = np.mean(piece)
    return sum_loss, err
```

data_mat is a 10000 rows and 3 columns numpy matrix
After trying, err = err.reshape(-1, 1) can fix this problem, but i still dont understand why the shape of err is (10000,) instead of (10000, 1) so that i have to reshape explicitly.

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. It's not clear what `getRandomBatch` and `computeLossFunction` are.

Comment: @Praveen Update question now, reshape err explicitly does work but i still dont understand why the shape of err is (10000,) instead of (10000,1)

Comment: In `computeLossFunction` `data_mat` is 3d, but with indexing `rates` is 1d.  Similarly the `sum` reduces the dimensions of its inputs, so `dot_list` is also 1d.  Remember this is `numpy`, not `MATLAB`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**On the array that is `(10000,)` use `.reshape(-1, 1)`, or vice versa on the other array.**

It's also apparent from your code that `data_mat` is 2d, not 3d, which may be the source of your confusion.  I.e.:

```
data_mat = np.empty((10000, 3)); data_mat.ndim
Out[9]: 2

data_mat[0, :, 2]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-4b9c676abc55> in <module>()
----> 1 data_mat[0, :, 2]

IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Comment: It works, but i still dont understand why the shape of err is (10000,) instead of (10000,1), the function `getRandomBatch` and `computeLossFunction`  is shown above